# Adding a table to a particular Div in the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

Just for testing, I made a page with nothing but the form and div tags and, in the codebehind, I created a table, added rows to it, then used the following code to add the table to the page:

```
Page.Controls.Add(dtStatuses);
```

What I'd like to do now, though, is add this table to a particular div.  For instance, if I have a div tag with an ID of "testDiv", how can I add the above table (dtStatuses) to that div, with just code in the codebehind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `runat="server"` to the div

```
<div id="testDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

and add the control like this

```
testDiv.Controls.Add(dtStatuses);
```